# Convert a 2D net to a 3D position

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

I'm currently working on an augmented reality project, and basically would like to render an object on a pattern.
I already have detected the pattern, and the coordinates of all the intersection.:

[image: Pattern detection]

What I would like to know is if there was a way to convert this 2D "net", into a 3D Cartesian coordinate system, in order to feed it to the render engine.  Like this:

[image: 3D vectors]

I know it is doable manually with some geometry,  but isn't there an already built-in way do do so?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You want to draw something over that chessboard? You wanna find out where in space it's hanging? You want a transformation that puts an image where the chessboard is?

Comment: I want to put 3 vectors creating a coordinate system on this net. The further the image is, the smaller the vectors would be.
This : http://i.imgur.com/tzDRMfd.png

Comment: If you have the 3D coordinates of all the intersections, what is the issue? You get red and blue by subtraction, and green by cross product. I doubt that there is any build-in methodology (needed) for this.

Comment: Well, you want a rotation matrix that transforms the unit vectors into two of those colored arrows (I forget the colors, but those on the plane). The matrix has three degrees of freedom and you get four equations from those two vectors, so just solve it.

Comment: @Niko: No the coordinates I have are only 2D, that's the problem. I only have the position on the picture of these points.

Comment: Did you do a camera calibration to get the camera's intrinsics? If so, you could use `solvePnP()` to get the calibration pattern's pose. With the vectors `tvec` and `rvec` you should be able to transform the coordinates of the object you want to draw to the camera's coordinate system. With `projectPoints()` you can project these 3D points to the camera's image plane.